# uninstall pear in wamp

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

By mistake i installed PEAR ,

I think i installed very wrongly,

Now i want to uninstall only PEAR ,

Tell me How to uninstall PEAR IN WAMP..

(For Localsystem)

Comment: Somewhere else I saw "pear uninstall pear". Linux people might need to use sudo, I am a Windows person. For Windows we probably must run a command prompt as an administrator. For Windows we probably should remove the registry update too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PEAR is just a set of PHP libraries. Just manually delete your PEAR folder and you are good to go.

Comment: but u see , i got this error when run just localhost in my browser,

    ""Warning: Can not find config file, please specify the $pear_user_config variable in /index.php
Error: the template directory (C:\php5\pear\data\PEAR_Frontend_Web\data\templates) is not a directory, or not readable. Make sure the 'data_dir' of your config file (C:\php5\pear\data) points to the correct location !

Comment: You are probably using some script that requires PEAR. I'd say you just need to set some configs inside this script for it to work (like include path).

Comment: @OndrejSlinták I don't think that is accurate information, as I believe there are other files left scattered somewhere, other than the Pear folder

Answer (score 0):

In windows 8:
Delete file C:\Windows\pear.ini.
Delete your PEAR folder.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the accepted answer, you can just manually delete the PEAR folder. However, when I installed PEAR, it added the following line to php.ini:

`include_path=".;C:\path\to\pear"`

Make sure to remove this line and to restart your webserver afterwards.

Also, maybe the path to PEAR was also added to your Windows' PATH variable. If you do not want to reinstall it to the same directory, you should remove that path as well.